# C++ Multi threaded directory scan code

Tags: c++, multithreading

I was looking how to write a multi threaded C++ code for scanning directory and get list of all files underneath. I have written a single threaded code which can do and below the code which can do that.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/stat.h> /* for stat() */


using namespace std;
int isDir(string path)
;

/*function... might want it in some class?*/
int getdir (string dir, vector<string> &dirlist, vector<string> &fileList)
{
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *dirp, *dirFp ;
    if((dp  = opendir(dir.c_str())) == NULL) {
        cout << "Error(" << errno << ") opening " << dir << endl;
        return errno;
    }

    while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
        if (strcmp (dirp->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(dirp->d_name, "..") != 0) {
            //dirlist.push_back(string(dirp->d_name));

            string Tmp = dir.c_str()+ string("/") + string(dirp->d_name);
            if(isDir(Tmp)) {
            //if(isDir(string(dir.c_str() + dirp->d_name))) {
                dirlist.push_back(Tmp);
                getdir(Tmp,dirlist,fileList);
            } else {
  //              cout << "Files :"<<dirp->d_name << endl;
                fileList.push_back(string(Tmp));
            }

        }
    }
    closedir(dp);
    return 0;
}

int isDir(string path)
{
    struct stat stat_buf;
    stat( path.c_str(), &stat_buf);
    int is_dir = S_ISDIR( stat_buf.st_mode);
//    cout <<"isDir :Path "<<path.c_str()<<endl;
    return ( is_dir ? 1: 0);
}

int main()
{
    string dir = string("/test1/mfs");
    vector<string> dirlist = vector<string>();
    vector<string> fileList = vector<string>();

    getdir(dir,dirlist,fileList);
#if 0
    for (unsigned int i = 0;i < dirlist.size();i++) {
        cout << "Dir LIst" <<dirlist[i] << endl;
        //string dirF = dir + "/" + dirlist[i];
        //getdir(dirF,fileList);
    }
#endif
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++)
        cout << "Files :"<<fileList[i]<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now issue is that it is single threaded and I need to scan say about 8000 directories under which file can be present. So I am not getting how to do so as number of directories can vary as it is decided by N dimension matrix.

Any help in this regard will be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the N-dimension matrix is that you refer to. But to answer your question, you ultimately have to do a parallel depth-first search. I assume you know how to do multithreaded programming already; if not, then you need to learn about that, preferably with the Boost library rather than just POSIX threads.

Comment: Basically with N-dimension matrix I want to say let say we have a 20x20x20 matrix then I will have 8000 directories which need to be searched. So this can be increased based on requirements.

Comment: To get good performance, whatever you define that to be for this application, ultimately your hardware (and OS) will also have to support this.  Usually I/O is a bottleneck for multithreaded apps, even if you split up the work into different threads, they tend to all wait for access to the same I/O, thus limiting any parallelism you hope to achieve.

Comment: Directory scans are **always** going to be limited by secondary storage, not CPU time. Multithreading will likely make this perform worse, not better.

Comment: @Billy Good point. Multithreading would only help if the directories are on different disks, like in a heavily distributed file system. It's unlikely the OP has that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

boost::filesystem has directory_iterator and recursive_directory_iterator, the former will get all the contents of a directory but not recurse sub-directories,  the latter will also recurse subdirectories.

With regard to thread-safety, you could lock a mutex then copy the results into a std::vector or two vector instances, one for files and one for directories, in which case you will at least have a local snapshot copy.

To actual "freeze" the file-system at that point to stop any process modifying it is not something you can normally do - well you could try setting the file attributes on it to read-only then change it back later but you will need to have permission to do that first.

Comment: I can't use boost::filesystem calls as the current code didn't support it. So I need to work on something generic C++ data structure only. Also I will be working on the approch you provide to see how we can get a good performance. :)